# Android Studio Rendering Problems, classes could not be found

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated the sdk. I've created a new layout XML with just a FrameLayout and a TextView. And I got a rendering problem:

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout

I've tried, but none did work. how can I fix it?

Comment: I would suggest you to switch to API 19 and Holo Dark, No Action Bar when you render the view. That's how I usually solve rendering problem (not always work). I read from somewhere before, saying that this is just a bug in Android Studio.

Comment: Try cleaning the project several times

Comment: Thank you.Your suggestion did work.And it's definitely a bug in Android Studio,I switch to other theme and then switch back, several times,then the problem is gone.

Answer (score 22):

There is a bug in the Android Gradle plugin that will be fixed for version 1.2.3. The bug is described here: http://tools.android.com/knownissues as well as two workarounds. Below is the one I used successfully:

> Workaround 1: First manually build the project (Build > Rebuild project), then manually sync the project (using the Sync with Gradle files in the toolbar, or from the Tools > Android menu), then finally press Refresh in the toolbar above the layout editor.

Answer (score 4):

Try to change the theme to something different than "AppTheme".
I had the same problem and that's how I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply rebuilding the project **Build --> Rebuild Project** solved for me

Answer (score 1):

I changed the android version used to render layouts from 22 to 17 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set minSdkVersion up API 21.
If your minSdkVersion was 21 or 22,this error won't be display.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner in Android development, I faced the same rendering issue while building my first simple program as "Hello World".
I thought the issue could be in locating Android SDK path. But, my experiments show it is a Bug in Android Studio 1.1 .
When I selected any API below API 20 as minimum acceptable API, I got above rendering error. For eg. I tried with API 15 (Android 4.0.3) or API 8(Android 2.2) as minimum supported API I got the error.
But when I put any API above API 20 as minimum supported API, the build ran successfully and I could see the output.

I know what worked and what didn't but why it happened and how to get around this for lower API version support is something I am looking forward from experienced programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a SDK causing the problem . 
Its the Android Studio as far as i know ( correct me if i am wrong )
To avoid this bug you can just rebuild your project by going to 
**Build -> Rebuild Project .**

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the theme "AppTheme" to **Light**
it works for me